# Possible conflict between langmap and Vimroom

Tags: vim

Having recently gotten 'serious'(-ish) about using Vim, I was really pleased to come across the 'VimRooom' script.

**Problem**

The problem is that I've also just discovered the langmap option for re-configuring the hjkl keys and there seems to be some sort of conflict which stops the new configuration of movement keys from working with Vimroom toggled on.

**Question**

I'm afraid to say that I don't understand the langmap command enough to know why such a conflict is possible and I was hoping someone could explain the problem/suggest a fix please?

My current .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible               " be iMproved

filetype off                   " required!
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

" My Bundles here:
"Bundle 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
"Bundle 'vim-scripts/CSApprox'
Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Bundle 'dnebauer/AutomaticLaTeXPlugin'
Bundle 'mikewest/vimroom'

" vim-scripts repos
Bundle 'L9'
Bundle 'FuzzyFinder'
" non github repos
Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'


" Colour scheme options
syntax on
set background=dark
set t_Co=16
let g:solarized_termcolors=16
colorscheme solarized

"Line formatting options
set linebreak
set tw=100
set fo+=t
"set foldcolumn=12
set tabstop=4

"Basic Keybindings
"Movement
set langmap=hk,mj,th,nl,kt,jm,ln

"Display options
set scrolloff=999

"Settings for Automatic LaTeX
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
filetype on

"Search Settings
set smartcase

"Vimroom Settings
let g:vimroom_sidebar_height=0
```

N.B. The desired hjkl remapping(for lack of a better phrase) only makes sense when using the Dvorak layout.